# ipconfig available over ssh, but not on the machine itself

Tags: ssh, kali-linux, raspberry-pi

I have Kali 4.19 loaded onto a Raspberry Pi 4, and am communicating with it using a ParrotOS VM on a separate host.

I noticed some strange behavior when sending commands to my Kali Pi over SSH. I can send familiar commands such as `ifconfig` and `shutdown` to it, and both have the expected behavior (the former shows the correct information about the remote machine, and the latter shuts it now).

When on the Kali Pi itself, if I open up a terminal and type either of the above commands, I get

```
brendon@kali:~$ ifconfig
bash: ifconfig: command not found
brendon@kali:~$ shutdown
bash: shutdown: command not found
```

I understand that `ifconfig` is deprecated, and that `shutdown` can come from different packages, so neither is necessarily guaranteed to exist.

What confuses me though is that it works over SSH, but not when on the machine. I assumed when I send a command, it gets encrypted as text, sent to the other machine, decrypted to text, then eval'd locally using a `exec*` call or something similar. Then the reverse happens to the response. That fact that it works over SSH though suggests that something else is going on.

If I `which ifconfig` over SSH, I get a return code of 1, which indicates that "one or more specified commands is nonexistent or not executable". And yet it still works.

Can someone explain what's happening here?

Comment: Is it the same user locally and via SSH? What is the output of `type ifconfig` in the SSH shell?

Comment: @HaukeLaging Yes, the same user for each test. And `type ifconfig` gives `ifconfig is hashed (/usr/sbin/ifconfig)`.

Comment: Then `$PATH` is different in the local shell from the remote?

Comment: Doh, sorry. Yes. This ended up being a dumb question. The SSH session contains `sbin` directories, whereas the local session doesn't. I'll just change the default PATH on the machine. Thanks.

Comment: However, I have no idea how that could happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something creates a difference between the `$PATH` setting for the local shell and the remote shell. The reason for the error message is that the parent directory of `ifconfig` is missing in the local shell `$PATH`.

Comment: I haven't changed anything, so it might be due to the default setting of Kali (I have very little experience with Kali so far). It seems a bit odd though that SSH sessions have access to more locations than sessions on the machine.